# Double Linked List crush

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Doubly Lined List with tail and head.

Could you show me where i have made a mistake

All code on GitHub here : 
https://github.com/ZSzymon/Circual-Double-Linked-List

I'm thinking that the problem is destructor

```cpp
ListV2::~ListV2()
{
    Node *current = head;
    Node *nextNode;
    while(current->next)
    {
        nextNode = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = nextNode;
    }

}
```

Taking your advice i changed destructor into this:

```cpp
ListV2::~ListV2()
{

    Node *nextNode;

    while(head)
    {
        nextNode = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete nextNode;
    }

}
```

Tried some debugging. Got this error 
"The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x9a3848, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0xfffffffffeeefef2, flags=0x0 (first chance)."

This is Node struct

```cpp
struct Node
{

    std::string data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    Node(std::string data):data(data)
    {
        next=nullptr;
        prev=nullptr;
    }

};
```

The program is crushing while delete myList;

Comment: Did you debug the code just before it crashs? Btw. your destructor has a flaw. You don't consider the case of empty list, i.e. `head == nullptr`, i.e. `while(current->next)` is U.B. in this case. If this is your problem I cannot say from exposed code. (I didn't look into github.) But, if you don't destroy a (n empty) list before your print crashs that's probably not your only issue.

Comment: Thinking twice, I believe `while (current->next)` should be `while (current)`. Otherwise, think what happens if your list contains e.g. exactly one node. (IMHO, this produces always a one node memory leak. However, a memory leak is annoying but not critical on first hand.)

Comment: What about printing ? 
void ListV2::printList()
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Empty List\n"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    Node *temp = head;
    for(size_t i=0 ; i++<size ; temp=temp->next)
        std::cout<<temp<<" :: "<<temp->data<<std::endl;
}

Comment: Beyond what Scheff said, there is no need for `current` anyway. Since the whole list is going down you can just use `head`. As in, `while (head) { Node *nextNode = head; head = head->next; delete nextNode; }`

Comment: That's not the way how this site works. Please, make a [mcve] which is fully exposed in question. (You may [edit] your question to fix it.) And, please, have a look at [ask].